# Is it possible to have a varchar(max) column for an ActiveRecord object type?

Tags: sql-server, castle-activerecord, varcharmax

I really want to have a column of inifinite length for one of the properties of my ActiveRecord object of type string, but I don't know how to set it.  When I set the length to -1 (the number for MAX in SQL server) I get an error.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: I meant to say *Castle* ActiveRecord.

Comment: This is not Ruby's ActiveRecord, right? Which one then?

Comment: didn't Length=8000 work? anything above 4000 should produce a MAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.  Apparently if you set the length to anything greater than 4000 it will set the column to MAX length.

Answer (score 1):

the varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) type is suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

set the data type of the column to text....

Comment: Where do I add that?  Here is my property declaration:

        [Property(NotNull = true, Length = 8000)]
        public string Data { get; set; }